# Blackberry midlet issue while running

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How to implement this in blackberry:

```
Display.getDisplay(midletObject).setCurrent(alert);
```

I don't have any midlet object, rather a UiApplication object, so I get error when I implement that method.

Comment: I think you are confused between Midlet & Blackberry Application.........

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hi dude Check [Programming the BlackBerry With J2ME](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-139239.html) so you can understand how it works. Thanks